# Why does the FileField in the models need a default?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am using Django and I am trying to create a file uploader and have various FileField in the models. When I try to do,

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

It prompts to set a default for the FileFields, why is it important? It says it is a non-nullable field, but why can't it be null?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you did not set `null=True` in your model. As [stated in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-options), every model field in Django can be null.

Answer (score 0):

Bacause the default is both false for null and blank.Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null).